# Is there any influence of the main process when launching a subprocess with subprocess.Popen?

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, pyqt5, subprocess

I'm trying to find information about "side effects" of launching Windows process with the `subprocess.Popen` library of Python.

I've heard that there are some good/bad practices for launching Windows commands from Python, and a big software company is blaming my software for making his crash, so I wonder if there is really any side effect.

Here is a snippet to explain my self:

```
def execute_command(command, env=None):
    res = subprocess.Popen(command,
                           shell=True,
                           stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                           stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
                           env=env,
                           creationflags=subprocess.CREATE_NO_WINDOW)

    start = time()
    output, error = res.communicate()
    execution_time = time() - start

    if output:
        output = output.decode(_SYSTEM_ENCODING, errors='replace')
    else:
        output = ""

    if error:
        error = error.decode(_SYSTEM_ENCODING, errors='replace')
    else:
        error = ""

    return res.returncode, output, error, execution_time


def start_software():

    # do some stuff

    execute_command('"C:\Program Files\Software\Software.exe" --foo --faa ')

    # do some other stuff


# This to avoid blocking my
# pyQt5 graphical interface, because the windows command 
# may be running by days or hours
th=Threading.thread(target=start_software)
th.start()
```

So as far as I know, the command is launched in the same way that a user would type the command in a cmd, it is launched in a separate process and do not shares the same memory with the main process.

My snippet is included in a Python 3.7 Qt5 software, compiled with pyinstaller, and they say that since my graphical interface includes HTML, the windows library MsHTML is being used, and its causing the second software to crash...

Comment: The function name is not a valid Python symbol. You seem to be reinventing `subprocess.run`, with unnecessary threading around it to boot. You could probably defend the use of bare `Popen` if you simply returned the process object, and waited for it when you require its results. The subprocess will then run in parallel with the main program until you try to communicate with it.

Comment: The first name had a typo, and as I said, this is only a snippet, `start_software()` is a really big function with a long algorithm, so it runs in a thread for not blocking the graphical interphase. I include here to give as much details as possible but its not necessary if you only run this snippet.

Comment: We still need some more context. You say that your GUI "includes HTML". In what sense? If you're using QtWebEngine, it does not use MsHTML: it's a chromium build that is embedded within the Qt module. And, in any case, it seems strange that this would cause the "second software" (which software?!) to crash. As far as we can understand from your description, which is still a bit vague, it may also be *their* fault.

Comment: @musicamante , yes, I doubt it is my software. PyQt5 ui editor uses some html, for when adding an image into a label, or css code to define styles. But that’s all, I dont even use the webengine. For me it has no sense what they are saying.

Comment: Bug-free software will not crash regardless of the mechanism used to launch the software.  Instead of shooting the messenger, the big software company should thank you for finding a way to reproduce the fault, and take advantage of this opportunity to reproduce, diagnose, and fix the bug in their program.

Comment: @stack92 The HTML capability of Qt widgets only provides a [limited subset](//doc.qt.io/qt-5/richtext-html-subset.html) that is always interpreted by an internal Qt parser, converting it into QTextDocument structures; in fact, the source HTML is always discarded (except for QLabel) as shown by the *huge* differences a QTextDocument outputs with `toHtml()`. Similarly, Qt style sheets are not real CSS, they're just based on that, and there's no HTML involved. If you're actually only using the above, their claims are just bullsh*t, and they clearly don't know what they're talking about.

Comment: Thank you @JeremyFriesner and musicamante . I’m face of a 54 billion euros company that it is trying to discreditate my software which such argument. The information about Qt it is very useful, I’ll investigate that to defend my work!

Comment: @stack92 Besides, even assuming that you were actually using QtWebEngine (which, as said, is an *internal* Chromium build embedded in Qt, MsHTML has absolutely nothing to do with it), separate processes don't share the same memory space (that's why we need to use pipes and serialization with them), and I don't really see how that should eventually affect the other app. The only case I can think of is that it operates under a specific environment they use, but if the command works as standalone, that shouldn't change that much (unless there's some implication with the pyinstaller environment).

Comment: @musicamante yeah it works like an stand-alone, and actually one of the biggest utilities is that when their software crashes, I'm able to get all the debug info and send it to the support teams. For me it was very important to launch this in a separate process so my software does not crash when theirs do.

Comment: At the [subprocess docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#security-considerations), it states that using `shell=True` can lead to shell injection problems (fixed only in version 3.12), so its usage is discouraged. That aside, I also don't see how an external process could crash a whole application (after it started running). Unless, of course, there was some exception being generated [before the child process started running](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#exceptions).

Comment: `shell=True` is inherently unsafe; see [Actual meaning of `shell=True` in subprocess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3172470/actual-meaning-of-shell-true-in-subprocess). What was fixed in 3.12 was apparently a Windows-only peculiarity which would manifest if you had a malicious `cmd.exe` in the current directory.

Comment: Does the problem still manifest if you remove PyInstaller from the equation?

Comment: Thanks @CarlHR , I wasn’t aware of that and I’m using python 3.7. I will put it to False. Actually thanks to this, I understand now why in second version of my software I had to start quoting the commands.

Comment: @tripleee is there any reason why would py installer would cause problems? Actually my application (with or without pyinstaller) never crashes, I don’t even have console warnings from qt or other libraries

Comment: Not particularly; just that the subprocesses in particular might be the wrong tree to bark under (but Windows is weird so personally I would not rule out _anything.)_

Comment: @tripleee yeah I usually use pstree to check that, but on windows it seems to be done with "Process Explorer". I checked and the tree is okay, the subprocess are below their parent. The only weird thing, is that If I kill my software, the tree regarding the other software breaks.

Answer (score 0):

This is rather speculative, but hopefully at least vaguely useful for directing your efforts.

[Process isolation](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_isolation) if properly implemented should prevent any two processes from disturbing each other. In fact, I would predict that your problem lies elsewhere, even on the rickety platform that is Windows.

Where your problem is *somewhat* more likely to lie is in conflicting use of some OS resource. The addition of threading might be contributing to that. If the GUI parts of your program are using something which isn't thread-safe under the hood, and the competing program is doing the same thing, the result could be a crash, or worse.

Unfortunately, at this level of detail, it's impossible to offer more than wild speculation, because we don't have access to the competing program, or the parts of your program whiqh are interacting with the component which is actually crashing.

Comment: Thanks for your response, and just to be sure that it is clear for me, are you saying that the GUI threads could mix/crash with the threads of the software (in the separate process) ? Or you are only talking about OS resouces? (Ports, files, etc.. )

Comment: My first intuition would be to check the documentation for the crashing component for notes on safe vs unsafe usage, but of course, in the worst case, the root cause is somewhere else and only incidentally exposed by this component. Also, it doesn't exactly help that this is Microsoft; expect their documentation to be on par with their first-tier support, which is stuck in an endless loop asking "are you sure the computer is on?"